# Is it legal to break into a property from which you are unlawfully evicted by the landlord while they are currently inside if you don’t threaten/harm?

Tags: england-and-wales, tenant, eviction, injunctions

The landlady gave no formal notices or court processes to end my lease or repossess the property. I was out of the property at the gym for less than 2 hours, and returned to find she had hired a locksmith to drill through the lock in the door. There was no notices served at all, much less court proceedings. I am intending to obtain an emergency injunction when the courts open, but even if I don’t do that or before I do that, is it okay to do exactly the same if she is in the property and objecting to that? I mean to hire a locksmith to break the lock and change it while she is still inside?

Comment: Probably not - but depending on the nature of your tenancy, the landlord [may have committed a criminal act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_from_Eviction_Act_1977).

Answer (score 2):

According to the charity [Shelter](https://england.shelter.org.uk/professional_resources/legal/possession_and_eviction/illegal_eviction_and_harassment/what_is_illegal_eviction#title-3), this is a bit of a grey area and you would be best advised having local government or the police present before you try to regain entry, in order to avoid being charged wth criminal damage:

> If the occupier decides to try to regain occupation, it is advisable for to have a tenancy relations officer and/or the police in attendance, so as to provide assistance in case of a confrontation with the landlord.

Answer (score -1):

Illegal or improper actions on the part of the landlord do not give you the right to reciprocate with your own illegal actions.  The property is not yours and you have been evicted.  To break in would likely be a crime just about anywhere.

You may have some legal recourse if the landlord acted illegally or unilaterally broke the terms of your lease.

Your best choice is to consult a local attorney who is familiar with rental properties, leases, and evictions.

Comment: I suggest that they have not been evicted, the landlord has just chosen to occupy the dwelling.  The landlord cannot just choose to enact a de facto eviction by showing up with a locksmith.

Comment: I suspect there is more to this story than we're being told.  But I believe my answer is still correct.  Breaking into the landlord-occupied apartment is likely to end badly for the would-be tenant.

Comment: The question is not whether the landlord's illegal actions permit reciprocal illegal acts, but rather whether re-entry with the help of a locksmith would be an illegal act.

Comment: I would be really surprised if a locksmith, which in many jurisdictions is a licensed profession, would agree to do this.  Once knowing that it's a rental property the first question is likely to be: "Why don't you ask the landlord to open the door?"